# Calculate day from static date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to calculate targets based as if they were on 01/01/2018,

Targets are calculated as target/5(days)*network days in month and then reduced based on start date 1/3, 2/3's full

The below code works well however this is calculating targets as of today and i need to amend this to calculate as of 01/01/2018.

I will then creating a new column for each future month.

when i amend the code and input a date rather than get date i get the below error

when StartDate < cast('2018-01-01' as date)-150 then cast(WeeklyIssueTarget as numeric(17,2))/5*23

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

```
Select *,
    case when StartDate is null then cast(WeeklyIssueTarget as numeric(17,2))/5*23 
    when StartDate < GETDATE()-150 then cast(WeeklyIssueTarget as numeric(17,2))/5*23
    when StartDate < GETDATE()-120 then (cast(WeeklyIssueTarget as numeric(17,2))/5*23)/3*2
    when StartDate < GETDATE()-90 then (cast(WeeklyIssueTarget as numeric(17,2))/5*23)/3*1 
    when StartDate < GETDATE()-89 then 0      end as Jan18
from Details
```

Comment: `GETDATE()-150` works for `DATETIME` and `DATETIME` alone. `DATEADD(DAY, -150, GETDATE())` works for all date/time types and is (arguably) easier to read as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getdate()` returns a `datetime`, not a `date`. So to be equivalent cast to `datetime` as well, instead of to `date`.

```
...
... cast('2018-01-01' as datetime) ...
...
```

To be safe and more verbose however, you might want to consider using [`dateadd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the calculations.